# What does $k(n - k)$ represent in combinatorics where $n \geq k \geq 0$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that $n \choose 2$ = $k \choose 2$ + $k(n - k)$ + ${n - k} \choose 2$ in the context of graph theory where $n$ is the number of vertices. I understand that $n \choose 2$ is the number of edges on an $n$-vertex complete graph, and the same holds for the third term on right of the equation, but I can't figure out what $k(n - k)$ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n$ vertices, and think about the complete graph on those vertices.
There are $\binom{n}2$ edges.
Colour $k$ vertices red, and the remaining $n-k$ vertices blue.
Then $\binom{k}2$ edges join two red vertices and $\binom{n-k}2$
edges join two blue vertices. What about the rest of the edges?

Comment: Ok, so I get that $k(n - k)$ is the rest of the edges as a fact, but I don't get why multiplying the two quantities counts this intuitively. I'm horrible at counting.

Comment: @dirtysocks45, because each of those edges connects one of $k$ red vertices to one of $n-k$ blue vertices. So you specify an edge by picking one red and one blue. If you like, think of it as ${k\choose 1}{n-k\choose1}$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide the set of $n$ vertices into two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $k$ and $n-k$ vertices respectively, $k(n-k)$ is the number of edges that join a vertex of $A$ and a vertex of $B$.

Comment: Why does multiplying the sizes of the two sets give the size of the join? I'm probably missing some set theory/counting argument about multiplying cardinality of two sets.